# How do you make a button appear when you press an <input> in HTML? How do you make a button that adds text in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am making a registration form. I have finished making the registration form, but I just need to add one more thing to the registration form: a button that adds text to the registration form. How do I make that button appear in the text input? Can someone help? Here is a runnable current snippet of the registration form:

```js
function ValidationForm() {
    let username = document.forms["RegForm"] ["Name"];
    let email = document.forms ["RegForm"] ["Email"];
    let phoneNumber = document.forms ["RegForm"] ["Telephone"];
    let pass = document.forms ["RegForm"] ["Password"];
    if (username.value == "") {
        alert("Please enter your name.");
        username.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (email.value == "") {
        alert("Please enter a valid email address.")
        email.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (phoneNumber.value == "") {
        alert("Please enter your telephone number.")
        phoneNumber.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (pass.value == "") {
        alert("Please enter your password.")
        pass.focus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

```css
.regform {
    margin-left: 70px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: sans-serif, bold, Arial, Helvetica;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.buttons {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
}
div input {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
form {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 600px;
}
form input {
    padding: 10px;
}
form label {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Registration Form</title>
        <script src="script.js" defer></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2 style="text-align: center;"> Registration Form </h2>
        <form name="RegForm" action="hidden for no hackers" onsubmit="return ValidationForm()" method="POST" class="regform">
            <div>
                <label for="Name">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="Name" size="60" name="Name">
            </div>
            <br>
            <div>
                <label for="E-mail">E-mail Address:</label>
                <input type="email" id="E-mail" size="60" name="Email">
            </div>
            <br>
            <div>
                <label for="Password">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" id="Password" size="60" name="Password">
            </div>
            <br>
            <div>
                <label for="Telephone">Telephone:</label>
                <input type="tel" id="Telephone" size="60" name="Telephone">
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="buttons">
                <input type="submit" value="Send" name="Submit">
                <input type="reset" value="Reset" name="Reset">
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Include your JavaScript and CSS code here also

Comment: Ok. I will include it.

Comment: It said that my post was mostly code.

Comment: Let me try again.

Comment: You still need more detail about the problem. I don't understand exactly what you want me to do. Add this information and Stack Overflow will let you add more code.

Comment: Ok, added it. Maybe you can help now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a "button that adds text":

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("input").value += "Text";
});
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click to add text to input below</button>

<br /><br />

<input id="input" />
```

Comment: I need someone to tell me, how to make the button appear when you press an <input> in HTML. Maybe you can help with that too?

Comment: @tt2806 I've updated my answer, the `<button>` now only appears when the `<input />` is in `:focus`

Comment: Hey, I'm sorry you have to hear this.. but.. I meant in my question: How to add text to <input>, sorry. Maybe you can update it again?

Comment: @tt2806 I've updated the code again. Is this what you wanted it to do?

Comment: The CSS is gone, did you remove it? I'm pretty sure you added CSS to your answer.

Comment: @tt2806 the CSS is not necessary unless you want the button to disappear and then reappear when something happens

Comment: Right now the button is always there and adds the text in the input when you click the button